# Cannot install libSBML in R

Tags: r, sbml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGRUE.png)
I'm trying to install libSBML in R, the installer for the Windows application I downloaded from github. However, this always fails with the prompt as shown in the picture. As a first time SBML user I don't really understand why this is happening. Do I need to install any other software to install this package? Any help would be appreciated.

Trying to install libSBML always fails. Download the software by following the instructions on the webpage https://sbml.org/software/libsbml/libsbml-docs/installation/#r. R bindings
libSBML-5.20.2 src archive. Hopefully the installation will be successful.

The following is what is displayed during installation

> install.packages("C:/Users/gengkuo/Downloads/libSBML_5.20.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
> Installing package into ‘D:/R/R-4.3.3/library’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

- installing *source* package 'libSBML' ...
  ** using staged installation
  mkdir: cannot create directory '/libs': File exists
  ** libs
  Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
  so building only the main architecture

using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 12.3.0'
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.3/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c OStream.cpp -o OStream.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.3/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c libsbml_wrap.cpp -o libsbml_wrap.o
In file included from libsbml_wrap.cpp:1865:
../swig/libsbml-packages.h:3:10: fatal error: arrays-package.h: No such file or directory
3 | #include "arrays-package.h"
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [D:/R/R-4.3.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:272: libsbml_wrap.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'libSBML'

- removing 'D:/R/R-4.3.3/library/libSBML'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/gengkuo/Downloads/libSBML_5.20.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Please paste text into your question. Using an image doesn't enable search engines to use this question to the full extent.